# Can only a private subnet access services via VPC Endpoint?

Tags: amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

Will only a private subnet be able to access the AWS VPC Endpoint?

I followed some of the tutorials across web, where everybody were using a private subnet to establish a connection to other services via VPC Endpoint. Can't a public subnet make private connection through VPC Endpoint?

Similarly, is it required that all the subnets be private at the client side (VPC Endpoint) in order to establish a private link (VPC Endpoint Services) ?

Answer (score -1):

Access to your VPC Endpoints is provided through adding specific route in route table.

For example you have *private* and *public* subnets. They have different associated route tables and for route table which is associated to private subnet you have route for your VPC Endpoint.

[image]

[image]

So you can add route to your VPC Endpoint to route table which is associated with public subnet (Or you can use the one route table for public and privates subnets).